# Почему не подключает зависимости в Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Нужно подключить зависимости по адресу https://github.com/VishnuSivadasVS/Advanced-HttpURLConnection
но оно не хочет их подключать и выдаёт ошибку :
Failed to resolve: com.github.VishnuSivadasVS:Advanced-HttpURLConnection:1.2
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите докуметацию к либе. В самом её начале написано, что надо указать репозиторий, в котором либа находится. Укажите

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

в `build.gradle` в корне проекта. Сразу на следующей строке после репозитория гугла - `google()`

Comment: И да, не лучшая идея - использовать эту либу для сетевых запросов. Она новая, малопопулярная, скорее всего не будет поддерживаться активно и, возможно, содержит баги. Используйте лучше де факто отраслевые стандарты - `OkHttp` и `Retrofit`

Comment: Я добавил в maven то что там указано

Comment: И это не помогло?...

Comment: Я изначально это сделал

Comment: Возможно автор репозитория что-то не так сделал и его либу просто нельзя подключить таким образом. Попробуйте написать ему issue на GitHub - возможно он даже вам ответит. А вообще - зачем вам эта либа? Скорее всего она вам и не нужна)